# Sum values in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a list like this, where the two collected numbers are sum together and deliver the final result of that sum `team1Goals + team2Goals`:

```
FT      4 + 1 - Atletico El Vigia v Llaneros de Guanare
Postp.  1 + 2 - Deportivo Lara B v Atletico El Vigia
Postp.  0 + 0 - Llaneros de Guanare v Urena SC
FT      1 + 0 - Rayo Zuliano v Universidad de Los Andes FC
```

Expected Result:

```
FT      5 - Atletico El Vigia v Llaneros de Guanare
Postp.  3 - Deportivo Lara B v Atletico El Vigia
Postp.  0 - Llaneros de Guanare v Urena SC
FT      1 - Rayo Zuliano v Universidad de Los Andes FC
```

I tried using the `sum()` method, but it gives me an error and even giving me a hint that I honestly don't know how to go about using:

> ***TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]***

```
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    stages = response['Stages']
    for stage in stages:
        events = stage['Events']
        for event in events:
            outcome = event['Eps']
            team1Name = event['T1'][0]['Nm']
            if 'Tr1OR' in event.keys():
                team1Goals = event['Tr1OR']
            else:
                team1Goals = '0'
            
            team2Name = event['T2'][0]['Nm']
            if 'Tr2OR' in event.keys():
                team2Goals = event['Tr2OR']
            else:
                team2Goals = '0'
            print('%s\t%s - %s v %s' %(outcome, [sum(team1Goals,team2Goals)], team1Name, team2Name))
```

Comment: Elaborate your question on `What you are getting?` and `What you want?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type cast the string variables to integers:

```
print('%s\t%s - %s v %s' % (outcome, sum([int(team1Goals),int(team2Goals)]), team1Name, team2Name))
```

Comment: Please edit your answear to complete model, like this: ```sum([int(team1Goals),int(team2Goals)])``` or ```print('%s\t%s - %s v %s' % (outcome, sum([int(team1Goals),int(team2Goals)]), team1Name, team2Name))```, thanks a lot for support! Perhaps older users may complain about your simple answer, I've seen it happen, so to lessen the chance of you losing points in the answer, I recommend doing this.

Answer (score 1):

So, The sum is only for integers, adding integers, That's what the error says, and has the solution too

Use: `variable_name = str(team1Goals) + str(team2Goals)`

Comment: Hi mate, I tried to use it like this, but the result was another error: ```TypeError: str.join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)```

Comment: The .join() function is used, to connect a list or other iterable element using a provided string. if you want to use the .join() function, you'd have to use it like this: ", ".join(goals), while goals could be a list. Read here for more reference: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp

Answer (score 1):

Sum can add up all values in a array given that they are of the same type. You can only use float and integers, while you have used strings.

Comment: Hi mate, would you have any way to add the answer on how I could modify my code so that the result I'm looking for is achieved? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that you need to add the numbers and not concatenate, so first convert them to integers using the int() function.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got your question correctly, but (now) as I understand is that we can change the STR to INT by doing the following:

`print('%s\t%s - %s v %s' % (outcome, sum([int(team1Goals),int(team2Goals)]), team1Name, team2Name))`

Comment: Hello mate, let's assume that I have ```team1Goals``` as ```1``` and ```team2Goals``` as ```5```, the result I expect is ```6```, but in your indication the achieved result is ```5```.